# Realtime Subscriber Count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

i've been wondering if there's a way to count a youtuber's subscriber count in realtime.

> I'd like to try and build my own counter if its possible.
>   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#choose-the-right-api-for-your- application